# Python script killed after opening an image using io.imread

Tags: python, scikit-image, steganography

```
from skimage import io
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 9999999999999999999999
io.imread('0.gif')
```

I have this simple script that open a corrupted GIF file for steganography thing, However, when I tried to open this gif file using **io.imread of skimage**, the script get terminated. I did some research about this error; I found out that the cause of error is not having enough RAM memory. This new error is shown, after I executed the script again with a new RAM memory:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 30.2 GiB for an array with shape
>   (78355, 103581, 4) and data type uint8
>   My question how can handle this error without handling memory?

[image: 0.gif]

Comment: You can use the PIL module to open the image.

Comment: Thanks, but I also need to calculate its MSE and SSIM. it seems gif image is not supported by PIL since it got this  error message : AttributeError: 'GifImageFile' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: What makes you think that a "corrupted GIF file" CAN be opened?  Apparently the corruption involved the file header (unless it's really supposed to be a 78355 by 103581 pixel image...), there is other critical data in the header that would make the rest of the file impossible to decompress if not acccurate.

Comment: PIL supports gif. The error you get comes from something else. You probably tried to do `img = Image.open(filename); img.shape`. You need to get the data first with `pixels = np.array(img); pixels.shape`. The memory error is clear though. You can't allocate this much space to read this image. Whether this is actually such a big image or just corrupted doesn't matter.